# Sorting ARIMA AIC in R

Tags: r, time-series, model-comparison

I have the following code which returns the model with the lowest AIC, but I want all the models with their AIC in ascending or descending order without using the built-in sort function in R

```
sp <- rnorm(100)  ## just some toy data to make code work!
spfinal.aic <- Inf
spfinal.order <- c(0,0,0)
for (p in 1:4) for (d in 0:1) for (q in 1:4) {
  spcurrent.aic <- AIC(arima(sp, order=c(p, d, q)))
   if (spcurrent.aic < spfinal.aic) {
     spfinal.aic <- spcurrent.aic
     spfinal.order <- c(p, d, q)
     spfinal.arima <- arima(sp, order=spfinal.order)
   }
}
```

I want `spfinal.order<-c(p,d,p)` to be a list of all models in ascending or descending order of AIC. How can I do that?

Comment: Could you explain why you want to avoid using `sort`?

Comment: Using functions like `order()` or `sort()` leads to superfluous computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below does what you want. As you want a record of all models having been tried, no comparison is done inside the loop. A vector `aic.vec` will hold AIC values of all models, while a matrix `order.matrix` will hold column-by-column the ARIMA specification. In the end, we sort both by ascending AIC values, so that you know the best model is the first one.

```
sp <- rnorm(100)  ## just some toy data to make code work!
order.matrix <- matrix(0, nrow = 3, ncol = 4 * 2 * 4)
aic.vec <- numeric(4 * 2 * 4)
k <- 1
for (p in 1:4) for (d in 0:1) for (q in 1:4) {
  order.matrix[, k] <- c(p,d,q)
  aic.vec[k] <- AIC(arima(sp, order=c(p, d, q)))
  k <- k+1
  }
ind <- order(aic.vec, decreasing = FALSE)
aic.vec <- aic.vec[ind]
order.matrix <- order.matrix[, ind]
```

I did not use a list to store the ARIMA specification, because I think a matrix is better. At the moment the matrix is in wide format, i.e., with 3 rows while many columns. You can transpose it for better printing:

```
order.matrix <- t(order.matrix)
```

Maybe you also want to bind `order.matrix` and `aic.vec` together for better presentation? Do this:

```
result <- cbind(order.matrix, aic.vec)
colnames(result) <- c("p", "d", "q", "AIC")
```

I think this makes it easier for you to inspect. Example output (first 5 rows):

```
> result
      p d q      AIC
 [1,] 2 0 2 305.5698
 [2,] 3 0 3 305.8882
 [3,] 1 0 3 307.8365
 [4,] 2 1 3 307.9137
 [5,] 1 1 2 307.9952
```